# Can't retrieve value from multiple radio in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm making a quiz website in Angular where the user has to choose the answer from multiple radio buttons.

This is the template that I have implemented. I'm using bootstrap.

```
<form [formGroup]="questionsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <div class="card mt-5">
                    <h5 class="card-header">1</h5>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"> Question 1</h5>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input me-1" fomrControlName="q1" name="q1" type="radio" value="0"> First checkbox
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input me-1" fomrControlName="q1" name="q1" type="radio" value="0"> Second checkbox
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input me-1" fomrControlName="q1" name="q1" type="radio" value="0"> Third checkbox
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input me-1" fomrControlName="q1" name="q1" type="radio" value="1"> Fourth checkbox
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input me-1" fomrControlName="q1" name="q1" type="radio" value="1"> Fifth checkbox
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mt-3 mb-5">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And this is the code in .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quiz',
  templateUrl: './quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quiz.component.css']
})

export class QuizComponent implements OnInit {

  questionsForm:FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.questionsForm = fb.group({
      q1:['',Validators.required]
    })
   }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.questionsForm.value)
  }
}
```

And in the console log, I get this. It's an empty string instead of 0 or 1.

```
{q1: ""}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are typo errors in the radio buttons. `formControlName` instead of `fomrControlName`.

Answer (score 0):

try fomrControlName="q1" instead formControlName="q1"